# Magento227 Maketplace Coding Standard Issue

Tags: magento2.2, marketplace, coding-standards

When I run: phpcs /path/to/module --standard=MEQP2
It gives me the following error

> PHP Fatal error:  Trait 'MEQP\Utils\Helper' not found in
>   /opt/marketplace-eqp/MEQP2/Sniffs/Classes/NameResolutionSniff.php on
>   line 23

phpcs -i
The installed coding standards are PSR1, PEAR, Zend, MySource, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz, MEQP2 and MEQP1

class NameResolutionSniff

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MEQP2\Sniffs\Classes;

use PHP_CodeSniffer\Config;
use PHP_CodeSniffer\Files\File;
use PHP_CodeSniffer\Sniffs\Sniff;
use MEQP\Utils\Helper;

/**
 * Class NameResolutionSniff
 * Dynamic sniff that detects the use of literal class and interface names.
 * Requires 'm2-path' to be configured.
 */
class NameResolutionSniff implements Sniff
{
    /**
     * Include Helper trait.
     */
    use Helper;

    /**
     * Violation severity.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $severity = 8;

    /**
     * String representation of warning.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $warningMessage = 'Literal namespace detected. Use ::class notation instead.';

    /**
     * Warning violation code.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $warningCode = 'LiteralNamespaceFound';

    /**
     * Literal namespace pattern.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $literalNamespacePattern = '/^[\\\]{0,2}[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+([\\\]{1,2}[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+){2,}(?!\\\+)$/';

    /**
     * Class names from current file.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $classNames = [];

    /**
     * A bootstrap of Magento application.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap
     */
    private $bootstrap;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function register()
    {
        return [
            T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING,
            T_DOUBLE_QUOTED_STRING,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function process(File $sourceFile, $stackPtr)
    {
        if (Config::getConfigData('m2-path') === null ||
            $sourceFile->findPrevious([T_STRING_CONCAT, T_CONCAT_EQUAL], $stackPtr - 1, null, false, null, true) ||
            $sourceFile->findNext([T_STRING_CONCAT, T_CONCAT_EQUAL], $stackPtr + 1, null, false, null, true)
        ) {
            return;
        }
        $tokens = $sourceFile->getTokens();
        $content = trim($tokens[$stackPtr]['content'], "\"'");
        if (preg_match($this->literalNamespacePattern, $content) === 1) {
            if (!$this->bootstrap) {
                $this->bootstrap = $this->getBootstrap();
            }
            if ($this->classExists($content)) {
                $sourceFile->addWarning($this->warningMessage, $stackPtr, $this->warningCode, [], $this->severity);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if class exists by class name.
     *
     * @param string $className
     * @return bool
     */
    private function classExists($className)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($className, $this->classNames)) {
            $this->classNames[$className] = class_exists($className) || interface_exists($className);
        }
        return $this->classNames[$className];
    }
}
```

and line no 23 is :

> use Helper;

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently faced the same issue. The current magento coding standard version is not compitable with latest code sniffer version. Try to install 3.0.0 of code sniffer version it will work.

Comment: My sniff version is PHP_CodeSniffer version 3.4.0

Comment: @Verdu degrade to 3.0.0 version.